# How to Properly Export CSV for Get-Mail Results?

Tags: powershell, csv, export, report, exchange-server

I am trying to export data of when email accounts have been created. The following code is what I am using:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Format-Table DisplayName, whencreatedUTC | Export-Csv -Path C:\Desktop\Reports\test.csv
```

Without the export cmd, the results come in just fine in PS. However, when the export cmd is added, my results turn out blank in the exported .csv file. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Format-Table`, use `Select-Object`. PowerShell treats all data as objects, but the `Format-*` cmdlets are for displaying the output, not for further processing. `Select-Object` takes the input (from the pipeline, in this case), and generates a new object with only the selected members, which you can then pass to `Export-CSV` for saving. You should also add `-NoTypeInformation` to the `Export-CSV` command, or you'll get a broken CSV with an extra line at the beginning.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Formatting does nothing for the .csv file since there is no data to be pulled from that cmd. `Select-Object` did exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you for teaching me something new!